# Cucumber setup in new Meteor project on Mac and Cloud 9 IDE

Tags: meteor, cloud9-ide, cucumberjs, meteor-velocity

I'm trying to use cucumber (via Velocity) in a brand new Meteor project.

```
meteor create cucetest
cd cucetest
meteor add xolvio:cucumber
meteor
```

I have tried this on OS X El Capitan 10.11 and also on a brand new Cloud 9 IDE Ubuntu vm (using `meteor --port $IP:$PORT`).

Unfortunately, after adding sample features Velocity reports an error, with the cucumber log showing the following:

```
[xolvio:cucumber] Bad response from Chimp server.
{ statusCode: 200,
  content: '',
  headers: 
   { 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
     'cache-control': 'no-cache',
     'content-length': '0',
     date: 'Fri, 23 Oct 2015 21:04:56 GMT',
     connection: 'keep-alive' },
  data: null }
```

Is there anything I'm missing as I'm itching to start writing features but can't get cucumber working on my Mac or Ubuntu dev machines?

Answer (score 0):

Grab the following Gist that I made:

https://gist.github.com/ffxsam/30905336d8cb43ed7b4d

This is a scaffolding script I use for every Meteor+React project. Never mind that it uses React, that part isn't relevant. You should be able to do `meteor run` and Cucumber should work perfectly (it takes a minute or two for the mirror to start up).

If anything, you can just look at the `tests` folder to see how things should be set up.

Comment: Thanks, will give it a whirl and see what happens.